# Kimono - Adding GUID to RSS output

Tags: javascript, rss, kimono

I'm using [Kimono Labs](https://www.kimonolabs.com/) to scrape data from a web page and create RSS output. Each item includes title, description and unique link. I want to use the feed as a trigger on IFTTT.com, but IFTTT requires that each feed item include a GUID. Is there a way in Kimono -- [perhaps here?](https://help.kimonolabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/203744354-Modify-your-API-results-with-a-javascript-function) --  to copy the link element and rewrite it to each item as a GUID? Thanks for any guidance you can provide.

Comment: Simply duplicating the link with a property name of GUID is not possible?

Comment: It looks like the only properties permitted in Kimono's RSS feed output are title (also be a link to the content), description, author, category, pubDate and comments. When I add the title text as "GUID" it just doesn't appear in the feed output.

Comment: Disqus RSS feeds don't have GUID and they work fine with IFTTT.com. My recipe: IF New Feed item from [http://disqus.com/username/latest.rss] THEN Create a link post on your Tumblr blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessary to have GUID to work with IFTTT. But if you do not have GUID, two things are mandatory:

- every item must have a distint URL;
- your RSS must be valid https://validator.w3.org/feed/.